# Phpstorm doesn't recognize php 5.2 installed manually

Tags: php, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug, php-5.2

I have a Vagrant/VirtualBox machine configured with ubuntu/trusty32 box.

I manually installed PHP 5.2 in the Vagrant box.

In PhpStorm EAP, when configuring remote PHP Interpreter, using Vagrant option (instead of SSH Credentials), PhpStorm can connect to Vagrant box (Vagrant Host URL field has the link to Vagrant box in blue and when I click on link, I get the successful message popped up).

Right below, at General section, PHP executable field, I select the PHP executable in my Vagrant box, but I get the message

```
PHP version: Not installed
```

The PHP info page is ok, including with `xdebug` info. The system is running well. The only thing is that I can't debug with `xdebug`.

Why I can connect with Vagrant box, but PhpStorm does not recognize the version of remote PHP?

UPDATE:
1) php.ini configuration for xdebug in php.ini:

```
zend_extension=/opt/php-5.2.17/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.profiler_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.40
```

2) output for `/opt/php-5.2.17/bin/php --version`:

```
PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Jun 29 2015 17:50:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: If you installed manually, did you get v5.2 in command line with `php --version` ? And for xdebug, are you configured it for remote debugging?

Comment: Well the problem persists. Phpstorm show the same error message `PHP version: Not installed` but at least I've got the xdebug works. The piece that was missing: IDE Key configured in firefox xdebug plugin differed from IDE Key in output from phpinfo().

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?